# Optimising noisy functions

Tags: r, optimization

I have a two-parameter function with typical output like this:
[image]
I need to identify the value of parameter 2 that gives a specified function output value for each possible value of parameter 1. So, for this example, say I need to identify the values of p2 such that the value of the function is 100,000 for each possible value of p1 - which we can see from the figure is a nearly-straight line from (approximately) p2=60 when p1=1430 to p2=25 when p1=1500.

I've tried to solve this using the `optimise` function in R and with the `optim_sa` function from the Optimization package (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/optimization/versions/1.0-7), in either case optimising for the minimum of `abs(target.number-function(p1,p2))`. However, it doesn't work at all well:

[image]

What's going on here is that the function is actually quite noisy at a small scale, and the optimisation functions are converging to local minima. Above a certain level of p2, the value of the function settles at an almost consistent value (~100) but randomly fluctuations between 100 and 100.1 - if the first two values the optimisation algorithm picks are in this range, it will converge to a local minimum created by these fluctuations. Below a certain level of p2, the value of the function rises exponentially, with much bigger random fluctuations, and so if the first two values the optimisation algorithm picks are in this range then it will converge to a local minimum here. Here's a fuller picture of the values of the function (this time on a log scale):

[image]

Is there any optimisation algorithm that can cope with this? It's rather frustrating because the pattern is so clear if you actually visualise all the combinations of values - so it seems like it should be easy! Or is there a totally different approach to this I'm missing?

Thanks! :)

Comment: What does the black line show? What you are describing does not seems to be inline with the plots you are showing where there is a clear-cut boundary.

Comment: the black line is the result of the optim_sa function - it should trace the shift on the colour scale that corresponds to 100,000, but often fails, which is what i'm trying to solve!

Comment: Did you look at the points where if fails? What were the conclusions?

Comment: it's either converging to very small random fluctuations in the function value for when p2>75, or converging to larger (but proportionally small) random fluctuations in the very high function values for p2<5 or so - it happens when both the first two points the optimisation tests are within those high or low ranges

Comment: Do you need exact solution or can you doo with optimizing a smoothed version---that is, to view the small-scale variation as noise. In that case, think in line of *response surface methods* (search this site) or fit a *surrogate function* and optimize that.

Comment: optimising a smoothed version would be fine! i'll look into response surface methods and surrogate functions - thanks for the pointers :)